# Unable to bind Model with Laravel Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following route entry:

```
Route::get('admin/user/edit/{id}', 'AdminController@editUser');
```

And given is controller Method:

```
public function editUser($id)
    {
        $user = User::where('id',1);
        return View::make('admin.edit_user')
            ->with('user',$user);
    }
```

All I want to bind model in my edit form which looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.admin_master')
@section('content')
    <div>
        {{ Form::model($user) }}
            {{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('first_name') }}
         {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
@stop
```

I can see text box but value is not being populated. `first_name` is column in my table `users`

I was trying to do what mention [here](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/laravel-form-model-binding)

Comment: `User::where('id', $id)` does not call on get or first, you can also consider `User::find($id)` which does a where on the primary key and loads the first result.

Comment: take a look: https://laracasts.com/lessons/form-model-binding and let me know if still unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public function editUser($id)
        {
            $user = User::where('id',1)->first();
            return View::make('admin.edit_user')
                ->with('user',$user);
        }

    @extends('layouts.admin_master')
    @section('content')
        <div>
            {{ Form::model($user) }}
                {{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name') }}
                {{ Form::text('first_name',$user->first_name) }}
             {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    @stop
```

Comment: `User::find($id);` or `User::where('id', $id)->first();`   `get()` will always return a collection

Comment: `->get()` loads multiple result, you probably mean `User::where('id',1)->first()` ? @lagbox beat me to it ;)

Comment: @lagbox Awesome. Kindly make it as an answer

Comment: @Volatil3 this answer shows how to solve that binding issue by properly getting the model, passing it to the view and binding it to the form.  Just make sure your form is going to the right route.

Comment: @lagbox I mean your solution does not need to set values manually. I asked to create a separate answer so that I accept and can be helpful for others